# How to use the input of one component in another - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm a new in Angular and I have a problem: I need to use one variable from ComponentA in ComponentB So this is my code below (I need to use "favoriteSeason" input result in component "Result"
Component A

```js
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn }
   from '@angular/forms';
   import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
   import { ResultComponent } from '../result/result.component';
   import { HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-answer-three',
     templateUrl: './answer-three.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./answer-three.component.css']
   })
   export class AnswerThreeComponent  {

     disableBtn: boolean;
     favoriteSeason: string;
     seasons: string[] = ['Cheesburger', 'Cheesecake', 'Fondue', 'Pizza'];
       submit() {
       this.disableBtn = !this.disableBtn;
       const result = this.favoriteSeason;
       console.log(result);
     }

   }
```

```html
  <div class="co">
    <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <div class="form-check">
        <h1>Choose a food:</h1>
      </div>
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
        {{season}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite food is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
    <nav>
      <div class="column">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableBtn" name="button" (click)="submit()">save

        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!disableBtn" name="button" (click)="submit()">
          <a routerLink="/result">Next</a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

And I need to use the result of "favoriteSeason" in component Result 
Component B

```js
   import { NgModule, Output } from '@angular/core';
   import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
   import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { AnswerThreeComponent } from '../answer-three/answer-three.component';
   import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';


   @Component({
     selector: 'app-result',
     templateUrl: './result.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./result.component.css'],
   })
   export class ResultComponent  {


   @Input () answer: AnswerThreeComponent;
   @Input () res: AnswerThreeComponent['submit'];

   @HostListener('click')
   click() {
    const result = this.answer.favoriteSeason;
    console.log(this.answer.favoriteSeason);
   }
   }
```

But i received an error - "can't find favoriteSeason name". What I do wrong? Thank you for any help and sorry if I wrote this question wrong (it's my first time)

Answer (score 2):

Sanchit Patiyal's answer is correct, but I would like to elaborate on that.

When you use the @Input() decorator on a component's field, that means that you now can set that variable in a parent component's template. Consider the following example:

Component A:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'aComponent',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html'
})
export class AComponent {
  inputValue: string;
  //doesn't matter what you do here
}
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
<bComponent [inputValue]="inputValue">
</bComponent>
```

Component B:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'bComponent',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html'
})
export class BComponent {
  @Input() inputValue: string;
  //this variable will be set by the parent component
}
```

```html
<h1>{{inputValue}}</h1>
```

This is an example of **one-way** data flow, meaning that the data only flows *into* the component B. Now if you need to get some data *out* of the component, you need to use @Output() decorator, which uses an EventEmitter to emit events out to the parent component when something happens. Let's introduce the third component, `cComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'cComponent',
  templateUrl: './c.component.html'
})
export class CComponent {
  @Output() output: EventEmitter<string>;
  
  private counter: number;
  
  click() {
    this.output.next(counter++);
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="click()">Click me!</button>
```

...and then edit our AComponent like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'aComponent',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html'
})
export class AComponent {
  inputValue: string;
  
  buttonClicked(event: string) {
    this.inputValue = event;
  }
}
```

```html
<cComponent (output)="buttonClicked($event)"></cComponent>
<bComponent [inputValue]="inputValue"></bComponent>
```

So, to recap, the component's output works just like other events (say `(click)` or `(focus)`), and can be used to get the data *out* of the component. HOpe this helps ;)

Welcome, by the way!

Comment: Thank you for the example - now I understand why the code was not working!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RxJS BehaviorSubject` for this. In this case we create a private BehaviorSubject that will hold the current value of the message which can be set in one component and get in other one. Follow this link for the tutorial.

[Sharing Data Between Angular Components](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Unrelated-Components-Sharing-Data-with-a-Service)

Comment: You can share data between angular components via services (both have access to the same instance) or via their parent component (if they have the same parent).

Comment: Yeah that depend if they have same parent but I don't see any relation between components in the question asked that's why shared the link :)

Comment: I didn't actually want to write this comment, was on mobile and thought this was the answer field :D It should have been an answer but I accidentally sent it too early